# Disable the Task action button

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting, interview-question

How can I disable the "Tasks ->" button in SQL Server Management Studio?

I need to prevent users scripting objects.

[image]

Comment: If the user has `VIEW DEFINITION` permission on the object in question, they can script the object.  If they *don't* have `VIEW DEFINITION` on the object in question, they will receive an error when attempting to script the object.